# Object updation inside loop with immutable state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was working on React application, where I need to update my objcet inside loop, 
my object structure is,

```
[{
    "iD": "101",
    "bD": "06/02/2018",
    "cD": "16/04/2018"
  },
  {
    "iD": "102",
    "bD": "06/02/2018",
    "cD": "16/04/2018"
  },
  {
    "iD": "103",
    "bD": "06/02/2018",
    "cD": "16/04/2018"
}]
```

My idea is I have to add few keys with every object, the approach which I took doesn't seem proper, because I am updating the object but not pushing the updated values in an array and returning the new values. Is there any other way around to update it with a mutation?

I was trying through for in loop:

```
let newList = {};
for (let key in list) {
    newList = Object.assign({}, list[key]);
    newList.newKey1 = 'demo1';
    newList.newKey2 = 'demo2';
};
```

Now If I return newList it will always have last updated value. So how I will get the full updated list. Array might have only one item as well like:

```
[{
  "id":"101",
  "bD":"06/02/2018",
  "cD":"16/04/2018"
}]
```

Comment: When you say "Object might have only one key as well" do you mean "Array might have only one item as well" ?

Comment: yes, like this,
let list = [
       {
          "id":"101",
          "bD":"06/02/2018",
          "cD":"16/04/2018"
       }
    ]

Comment: Seems like you assume `newList` to be an array, but why do you set it to an object then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this having an array and pushing every time updated obj in it.

ex,

```
const items = [
  {
    iD: "101",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  },
  {
    iD: "102",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  },
  {
    iD: "103",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  }
];


    let bObj = {};
    let uObj = [];

    for ( const item of items ) {
      bObj = Object.assign({}, item )
      bObj.newKey1 = 'Test1';
      bObj.newKey2 = 'Test2';
      uObj.push(bObj);
   }
   return uObj;
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert every item in an array to something else via straight mutation, you can just use a version of a for (`for..of` or `forEach`) loop:

```js
const items = [{
    iD: "101",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  },
  {
    iD: "102",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  },
  {
    iD: "103",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  }
];

for (const item of items) {
  item.newKey1 = 'demo1';
  item.newKey2 = 'demo2';
}

console.log(
  items
);
```

To convert every item in an array to something by returning a new array with items changed, you should use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const items = [
  {
    iD: "101",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  },
  {
    iD: "102",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  },
  {
    iD: "103",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  }
];

console.log(
  items.map(item =>
    Object.assign({}, item, {
      newKey1: "demo1",
      newKey2: "demo2"
    })
  )
);
```

Or with object spread if your environment supports it:

```js
const items = [
  {
    iD: "101",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  },
  {
    iD: "102",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  },
  {
    iD: "103",
    bD: "06/02/2018",
    cD: "16/04/2018"
  }
];

console.log(
  items.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    newKey1: "demo1",
    newKey2: "demo2"
  }))
);
```

Comment: One thing , Array.map will return new array altogether. Instead of just mutating the existing one. i think @priya wants to mutate it !!

Comment: @stack26 thanks for the comment, I added both solutions now

Comment: @nem035, I was trying same, but sill problem persists. In my react application, the object is not getting update. It is still returning old object. :(

Comment: @nem035 Also getting this error when I have multiple values, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property newKey1, object is not extensible"